# Обрабатывать событие keydown только в пределах нужного экрана

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Есть 2 блока, где нужно событие `keydown` они на разных экранах страницы, `keydown` общий. Как его ограничить, чтобы если видна одна область, то работает в ней? Или может фокусом кто-то делает? Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

1. Определи высоту экрана (window.innerHeight)
2. Определи величину прокрутки экрана (window.pageYOffset)
3. Определи положение нужных элементов страницы (element.offsetTop)
4. Проверь, является ли какой-то из элементов в границах экрана, если да то выполняй нужные действия по нажатию на кнопки.